# Magento - configurable products not showing up when searching

Tags: magento, search, product, configurable

When I search for a configurable product (by name, name fragment or SKU) the search does not return any configurable products. I can search for simple products.

The configurable products;

- Are in stock
- Are set to "catalogue / search" visibility
- Are visible in the categories and are purchasable

This is a multi-store setup and this issue only affects one store, so I'm assuming it's a configuration issue, but I can't find any setting that might stop configurable products being returned in a search.

I'm open to suggestions on this one, I'm pretty sure I've overlooked something silly - I just can't work out what!

Comment: Do the configurable products belong to the root category of the store ? Or is this category an anchor ?

Comment: Are your indexes up to date?

Comment: All indexes are refreshed and up to date. No products are in the root category of the store. I've picked a configurable product at random. It is in two categories and neither are anchors. The root category is not an anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked the issue down to a third-party search module. If you're having the same issue, disable any third-party modules that replace the standard Magento search function. If the problem still exists, see the other answers here for some good advice. If the issue resolves, you may need to contact the module publisher.

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is an old post, but for others: When working with configurable products you have to make sure that all simple products related to that configurable product are activated for the web site (this is different from "enabled" - see image). Even if one of the simple products for a configurable product is not enabled for the web site it will be sold on, the configurable product will not appear.[image: In this setup, all stores are on the same website, but if the store is split into more websites, this can be the reason for the products not showing up there.]

Comment: Thanks - a very valid point. Not the issue in this case, but it was still something that I had not checked.